# Image Mapping for ePaper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mapping

I'm working on a new project for a media company where I need to create their website something like their competitors [epaper.bhaskar.com](https://epaper.bhaskar.com/indore/129/08112018/mpcg/1/). After a bit of researching I found that they are using a plugin called [maphilight](https://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html). But my question is that do they manually provide coordinates for each area or is there an automated way to do this?

Another one of their competitors [erelego.com](http://erelego.com/newspaper-new.php?paperedition=Davanagere&papername=Udayavani) is also have this feature but I don't know what plugin or technology they are using and it seems like an automated process.

Any help and clarity regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Note- Even if there's any paid service to achieve this effect would also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Dreamweaver software for the coding please follow the guideline.

URL: http://myy.haaga-helia.fi/~woljo/dreamweaver/imagemaps/

Comment: I use sublime editor for coding and I know there are multiple ways to map an image, I want to know what's the best and easiest way to do it and which will suitable for an epaper website just like the ones I have mentioned in my question. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

This looks interesting for ePaper imagemaping project on github.

https://github.com/himstar/Advanced-Image-Mapping-Tool

Please check and share your experience.